# Unable to clone repository to jenkins on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am able to clone a repository that i've created for one of my jobs on jenkins. Whereas, cloning a repository which is a fork of another repository gives the following error when trying to build it - Any suggestions on what could be the problem?

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client1/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/client1/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1d5cac4
Using strategy: Default
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://..... (couldn't disclose the address link here)

    git --version
    git version 1.7.9.5
    ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone https://.....
    hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone https://......
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.clone(GitAPI.java:273)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1044)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:986)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:986)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1142)
        at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1331)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:682)
        at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:587)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1557)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
```

Comment: Could you try and rename the remote reference from origin to something else? `git remote rename origin somethingelse`. And see if Jenkins is able to clone it then.

Comment: Please excuse my basic question, can we do 'git remote rename origin somethingelse' before we could clone the repository to the local folder?

Comment: No: `git remote rename` will rename the remote address used by a local repo, meaning you need to have that local repo in the first place in order to execute the `git remote rename ...` command.

Comment: The repository i'm trying to clone is a fork of a public repository. Jenkins throws the above error when i'm trying to build the job. So i dont have a local repo to change the remote reference. I dont know why the jenkins is taking the remote reference as 'origin' by default!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that the user jenkins is running as does not have permission to access the git repo.

I would try logging into the server and running

```
sudo su <jenkins_user_name>
git clone https://.....
```

You may just need to add the server to your known hosts if the SSH Keys are already setup.